# Hashing/Email encryption

Tags: encryption, hash

I have a request to be able to encrypt emails so the sender cannot decipher who the receiver is.  Can we do this?

If not, can you please suggest alternative solutions?

In the clients words…

"can we have Hash emails so that we don’t see email addresses but we can email people?
How can we publish a list of emails that is all garbled so no one without the (complex) key can decipher it?
I want the email addresses to not be decipherable by humans
some mechanism on our end to garble the emails so no one but them can see it and us on the end but with a key (or better a computer with the key)
we have a list of very confidential emails
many people are generating that list
these emails cannot be discovered and are highly sensitive
how do we garble/encrypt these emails at the source and allow out computer system to use these encrypted emails?"

Best regards,
Gowri

Answer (score 0):

No. Addresses are always public. They need to be to be able to send anything to them. That doesn't need to mean that one knows who is behind the address, or that any information other than the routing can be extracted from the address. There's nothing sensitive about addresses.

You can garble your email addresses by using a simple translation table, but that only means that the garbled address will be the public-facing one.

Comment: Thanks for you reply!  can we encrypt email addresses with some key, so that we will be able to decrypt with the key generated while encrypting?

For EX: I send a list of encrypted email addresses with some unique keys (which are very confidential) from one country, Receiver from different country will decrypt all the email addresses with unique keys generated for each email address while encrypting.

Comment: Of course you can do that, but it leaves some questions: How does the receiver get the confidential keys? Why not send the adresses that way? And: what is gained in comparison to sending them unencrypted? **What is your threat scenario?** Btw, I'm not sure what you mean by "send" and "receive". Are you talking about sending emails, or just sending something that contains addresses as data?

Comment: Sender will send  a mail with encrypted email addresses and will send keys in different mail. These email ids are very confidential and should be discovered by any other person

Comment: Yes, if you send the encrypted data and the keys both per email you'll make sure that they will be discovered by some other person :-)

Comment: No, if the addresses are just data in the (attachment of the) email, it doesn't make much sense to encrypt them separately. Just use a [standard approach](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Email_encryption) to encrypt the email itself.